# The best way to handle config in large C++ project

Tags: c++

In order to start my C++ program, I need to read some configs, e.g. ip address, port number, file paths... These settings may change quite frequently (every week or everyday!), so hardcoding them into source files is not a good idea.

After some research, I'm confused about whether there is a best practice to load config settings from a file and made those configs available to other class/module/*.cpp in the same project.

static is *bad*; singleton is *bad* (an *anti-pattern*?) So, what other options do we have? Or, maybe the idea of "config file" is wrong?

EDIT: I have no problem of *loading* the config file. I'm worried about, after loading all those settings into a std::map< string, string > in memory, how to let other classes, functions access those settings.

EDIT 2: Thanks for everybody's input. I know these patterns that I listed here are *FINE*, and they are used by lots of programs. I'm curious about whether there is a (sort of) *BEST* pattern to handle configurations of a program.

Comment: I don't see why a config file is wrong.  It's been done before.

Comment: if your parameters need to change dynamically, use a XML parser with a config file. Otherwise a good ol' Constants.h with define/typedef/static constants does the job

Comment: If you're worried about static/singleton stuff, you can read in the file once and then pass it around to everything that needs it.

Comment: which actually gives it the same meaning as the word singleton "there's only one", but just doesn't implement it that way literally in code

Comment: Everything is _bad_, in some contexts.  For configuration files, singleton is fine.

Comment: Is your application a long running one that needs to dynamically get new settings, or is it a processes you run daily that just needs new parameters for ip/port etc.

Comment: @LokiAstari It only read the config at start. It's a long running program, but no setting changes during the runtime

Comment: If you want to avoid these anti-patterns and are doing string mapping throughout, store them into environment variables early in the start up process. Getting the config item can then be either immediate, or encapsulated in a short lived class instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguably, a configuration file is a legitimate use for a Singleton. The Singleton pattern is usually frowned upon because Singletons cause problems with race conditions in a multi-threaded environment, and since they're globally accessible, you run into the same problems you have with globals.  But if your Singleton object is initialized once when you read in the config file, and never altered after that, I can't think of a legitimate reason to call it an "anti-pattern" other than some sort of cargo-cult mentality.

That being said, when I need to make a configuration file available as an object to my application, I don't use a Singleton.  Usually I pass the configuration object around to those objects/functions which need it.

Comment: You're second solution means propagating the configuration through many layers which don't need it.  Especially for the types of data he mentions, the configuration will be used at the very lowest layers.  In this case, a singleton is by far the best solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze is right. If I pass the config object around, it has to go through many layers.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia - "I can't think of a legitimate reason to call it an "anti-pattern" [...]" The problem a singleton raises for me, is with refactoring/testing. While you can change the _values_ in your settings file, the singleton allows you to write client code w/o dependency injection, but by accessing the get-instance internally. This causes a deep, non-obvious dependency that tends to spread over the code base and can be difficult to replace later. If your settings class is simply not a singleton you keep all advantages, except the hidden non-centralized dependency issue.

Comment: I don't see a problem with passing the configuration through many layers, if ultimately the configuration **will** be modifying the behavior of those layers. The fact they delegate to sublayers is an implementation detail, from caller's perspective the configuration is used by the layer.

Answer (score 2):

The best pattern I know of solving this is through an options class, that gets injected into your code on creation/configuration.

Steps:

1. create an options parser class
2. configure the parser on what parameters and options it should accept, and their default values (default values can be your "most probable" defaults)
3. write client code to accept options as parameters (instead of singleton and/or static stuff).
4. inject options when creating objects.

Have a look at [boost.program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html) for an already mature module for program options.
If you're familiar with python, have a look at the [examples in the doc of argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) (same concept, implemented in python library). They are very easy to get the concept and interactions from.